# Search a string in Visual Fox Pro database

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Hi I have search this and maybe its impossible because I havent found anything.

I need to find a string in an entire Visual FoxPro database through command line, is this posible? not table by table.

Comment: Are you looking for a string in a table of the database? Perhaps you could open the database like this: USE myVFPDatabase.DBC  then SELECT * FROM myVFPDatabase WHERE objecttype = [Table] into cursor myresults  at this point, you have all the tables of the database. You could then perform a SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE fieldName1 Like "%SomeValue%" INTO CURSOR MyCursor

Comment: Jerry has some helpful ideas for searching the actual database container for a string, but Notforever, you are going to have to be more specific in your question. It is vague. For all we know, you may be asking how to search for a string in a field in a table in a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the GoFish search app for FoxPro and use it to search any DBF.

http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GoFish

DBF searching is not enabled by default, since it can create a loooong search if the tables are huge with lots of rows and columns, but you can add DBF to the file extension list in the FileTypes ares on then Advanced options page.

It runs from inside of the VFP IDE.

There is a video on the site, and a user group link as well where you can join to ask questions. You can also download the complete source code from the app.

Let me know if you need more help. (I am the author)